# Insertion Sort implementation with one recursive function and foldBack function

Tags: list, f#, insertion-sort

I am reviewing implementations for some basic data structures and the algorithms operating on them. I guess the idiomatic F# code for **Insertion Sort** is very much like:

```
let rec insert x = function
  | [] -> [x]
  | y::ys -> if x<=y then x::y::ys
             else y::(insert x ys)

and insertionSort = function
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs -> insert x (insertionSort xs)

let myLst = [8;3;3;5;-6;0;1;4;-3;2]
let result = myLst |> insertionSort
```

val result : int list = [-6; -3; 0; 1; 2; 3; 3; 4; 5; 8]

While I was trying to implement it with **List.foldBack** and only one recursive function, as below, and couldn't give me the correct result? Anyone can figure out where the problem lies?

```
let rec anotherInsertionSort lst =
  List.foldBack(fun x (ys:list<_>) -> 
                  if ys.IsEmpty then [x]
                  elif x <= ys.Head then x::ys
                  else ys.Head::x::anotherInsertionSort ys.Tail) lst []
```

Comment: In your `else` branch, `x` isn't used...

Comment: @kvb, oop... got it right now. Much appreciate! I'd have spotted it before posting.

Comment: @cfj FWIW, I always try to test any sample code before I post to make sure that it demonstrates the problem I'm asking about and that I haven't flubbed up anything else.  Saves time. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un-golfed from [cfern's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1721001/162396):

```
let rec insert i = function
  | h::t -> min h i::(insert (max h i) t)
  | _ -> [i]

let insertionSort l = List.foldBack insert l []
```

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, the problem is that you're dropping `x` in your `else` branch.  Here's one way to fix it:

```
let rec anotherInsertionSort lst = 
    List.foldBack(fun x ys ->  
                    match ys with
                    | [] -> [x]
                    | y::_ when x <= y -> x::ys 
                    | y::ys -> y::(anotherInsertionSort (x::ys))) lst []
```

Having said that, I like Daniel's approach better.

Comment: Agree. Daniel's approach is more elegant.